# Unique field value Django model

Tags: python, django

So, i have two models: `RetailStore` and `Product`. Product contains a ForeignKey to RetailStore and a field named `sku`. Basically what i need is to make sure that the `sku` field is unique into a store, but not between all stores, e.g:

`Store1: Product(sku="sku1"), Product(sku="sku2"), Product(sku="sku3"), Product(sku="sku1")` <- can't have this last one because it already exists.

`Store2: Product(sku="sku1"), Product(sku="sku2"), Product(sku="sku3")` <- This is ok

`Store3: [...]` <- Same goes for others Store.

### My Models

```py
class RetailStore(StandardModelMixin):
    cnpj = models.CharField(
        blank=False, null=False, unique=True, max_length=200, validators=[validate_cnpj], verbose_name="CNPJ"
    )

    [other fields...]

class Product(StandardModelMixin, SoftDeletionModel):
    sku = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=200, verbose_name="SKU")
    
    [other fields...]
    
    retail_store = models.ForeignKey(
        RetailStore,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="products",
        verbose_name="Retail Store",
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) so you can have the same SKUs in different stores, but not in one.

```
class Product(StandardModelMixin, SoftDeletionModel):
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['sku', 'retail_store'], 
            name='unique_sku_in_store'
        )]
```

Comment: Just a little tip, the models.UniqueConstraint needs to be iterable, to fix just wrap it with [constraints = models.UniqueConstraint(...)]. But it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to apply validate_unique to this.

Django offers unique_together, but it grants uniqueness to a single model and not between models.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique